# How to install frameworks 2,4 when i already have 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks

I recently installed VS 2013 with 4.5 framework on a new computer.
I have win 7 with 64x, i tried to installed those old fws but it says they are already included in the os.

The thing is that i try to open an old project that all its refernces are old versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can right click on your project file, then select target framework to the framework you are targeting (e.g. 2.0).

To find .NET Framework versions by viewing the registry (.NET Framework 4.5 and later)
On the Start menu, choose Run.
In the Open box, enter regedit.exe.
You must have administrative credentials to run regedit.exe.
In the Registry Editor, open the following subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full